# Unexpected character at end of import statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been following along with the Redux [Todo List example tutorial](https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist) recently, and I noticed there were some weird errors when I would try to implement it on my computer using `create-react-app`. I am familiar with using React, but for Redux I am more of a beginner. I simplified what I was trying to do, and this is the current error I cannot figure out:

```
./src/index.js
Syntax error: Unexpected character '​' (6:34)

  4 | import { createStore } from 'redux'
  5 | import rootReducer from './reducers'
> 6 | import App from './components/App'​
    |                                   ^
  7 | const store = createStore(rootReducer)
  8 | ​
  9 | render(
```

This is basically the same exact code you will find in `index.js` on the page I linked above, although slightly modified so I don't have to worry about the other files. I just cannot for the life of me figure out why this error is occurring.

Comment: Just delete the line and rewrite it by hand. Some times copy paste inserts junks in to the editors.

Comment: @ArupRakshit thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had almost same problem. I realized later than I created the file from command line (VS Code Terminal - windows-based) using command

```
PS D:\workspace\react-redux-demo\store>echo some-text > index.js
```

I then removed the text "some-text" and started writing code. However, I got the same error while doing npm run start!

I had to copy all the code, delete and create a new index.js (and paste the code) to get it work!!! Wierd, but there must be some non-printable characters which I, interestingly, could not delete using back arrow!!!